# Slick Generic Create Error

Tags: scala, crud, slick, slick-2.0

I get the following error and I don't understand what's wrong.

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[I] 
[error]   def id = column[I]("id",O.PrimaryKey) 
[error]                     ^
```

This error refers to the FkTable.  I've listed the code, along with the comments that show my intentions.  My plan is to make a nice foundation for tables that I can then make my CRUD service off of.

```
//ROWS
trait Row[I<:AnyVal,M[_]]{
  val id:M[I]
}
//TABLES
/**
 * @tparam I This is the type of the ID column in the table
 * @tparam M The row may contain a wrapper (such as Option) which communicates extra information to Slick for the row
 *           data.  M can be Id, which means that M[I] == Id[I] == I which means the Row item can contain a simple type.
 * @tparam R The class that represents a row of data.  As explained above, it is described by its __id__ which is of
 *           type M[I].
 */
abstract class BasicTable[I <:AnyVal,M[_], R <:Row[I,M]](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[R](tag, name) {
  def id: Column[I]
}

/**
 * @note The BasicTable takes Long,Option because longs can be incremented, and in slick this is communicated by an
 *       Option value of None. The None is read and tells Slick to generate the next id value.  This implies that the
 *       Row (R) must have a value __id__ that is an Option[Long], while the id column must remain Long.
 */
abstract class IncrTable[R <: Row[Long,Option]](tag: Tag, name: String) extends BasicTable[Long,Option,R](tag, name){
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
}

/**
 *
 * @param refTable
 * @tparam I This is the type of the ID column in the table
 * @tparam R The class that represents a row of data.  As explained above, it is described by its __id__ which is of
 *           type M[I].
 * @tparam M2 The Wrapper for the referenced table's id value
 * @tparam R2 The class that represents the referenced table's row of data
 */
abstract class FkTable[I<: AnyVal,R<:Row[I,Id],M2[_], R2 <:Row[I,M2]](tag: Tag, name: String,refTable:TableQuery[BasicTable[I,M2,R2]]) extends BasicTable[I,Id,R](tag, name){
  def id = column[I]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

  //Foreign Key
  def fkPkconstraint = foreignKey("PK_FK", id, refTable)(_.id)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slick's `def column[T]` requests an implicit `TypedType[T]` in its signature. Slick ships with `TypedType`s for `Int`, `Double`, `Date`, etc., but it can't find any one for the generic type `I`. You can request one in the constructor to `FkTable`. Just add a second argument list to FkTable as `(implicit tt: TypedType[I])`:

```scala
abstract class FkTable[...](...)(implicit tt: TypedType[I]) extends ...
```

This moves the implicit lookup to where `FkTable` is used, and `I` is probably set to a more concrete type. The `TypedType` value is then implicitly propagated through to the call to `column[I]`.

Comment: I had to add implicit for BaseTypedType[I] to make work ColumnExtensionMethods methods with I fields. (slick 3.2.1)